# Output of `top` command not saved to variable

Tags: bash, top

I created the follow bash script, called `./notify-me.sh`, in Ubuntu:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

emailmessage=$(top -b -o %CPU)
echo $emailmessage
```

But when I run this script by doing `./notify-me.sh` and pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the command prompt just skips to the next line and does nothing. It just stays on the empty line until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break the process.

How do I store the output of the `top` command to a variable?

Comment: Without a `-n` value, `top` will keep running even in batch mode (`-b`) - if you want a single-shot of output add `-n 1`

Comment: that worked!
```
#!/bin/bash

emailmessage=$(top -n 1 -o %CPU)
echo "$emailmessage"
```